# Duda sobre variable compartida volatile int

Tags: java, volatile

bueno tengo una duda con respecto al funcionamiento de volatile en Java.
si por ejemplo tenemos una variable "volatile int x = 0" y tenemos este código.

```
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
x++;
}
```

Si este bucle for lo ejecutan 5 procesos utilizando la variable compartida volatile, cuál sería el valor final de x y por qué?
Yo pienso que es 15 porque x es volatile pero un amigo me dice es 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No es posible saberlo, o mejor dicho, el valor final es inconsistente.**

Marcar una variable con el modificador `volatile` no la vuelve atómica, por lo tanto habrá lecturas y escrituras concurrentes que volverán inconsistente el valor final.

Piénsalo así, para modificar el valor un hilo debe hacer 3 cosas:

1. Leer el valor.
2. Calcular el nuevo valor.
3. Actualizar la variable con el nuevo valor.

Mira esta dinámica:

```
x = 0

Hilo A - Paso 1: Lee x = 0
Hilo A - Paso 2: Calcula x = 0 + 1
Hilo B - Paso 1: Lee x = 0
Hilo A - Paso 3: Escribe x = 1

x = 1

Hilo B - Paso 2: Calcula x = 0 + 1
Hilo B - Paso 3: Escribe x = 1

x = 1
```

El hilo A lee la variable, luego calcula su valor. Mientras tanto el hilo B lee la variable que aún no ha sido actualizada por el hilo A. Para cuando el hilo A actualiza la variable el hilo B ya la había leído y está calculando su valor, aquí se da la inconsistencia.

El valor final es imposible saberlo puesto que puede ser diferente cada vez que lo ejecutes. Probablemente 3 repeticiones para 5 hilos no sea suficiente para mostrar inconsistencias mayores, pero podrías aumentar el ciclo a 10_000 repeticiones para que las notes claramente.

Comment: Vale entonces no se puede saber ya que puede haber múltiples intercalaciones de instrucciones atómicas por asi decirlo no?

Comment: @Jorge En realidad el nombre técnico del problema es "Condición de carrera" por si quieres investigar más acerca de ello y sus posibles soluciones.